# router-link not rendering links properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to iterate over some data to produce my `router-link`s

```
<router-link v-for="(data, dataKey) in dataObject"
            :to="{ params: { dataKey: dataKey }}"
            tag="li">
  <a>
    <span>
      {{ dataKey }}
    </span>
  </a>
</router-link>
```

This creates the tags with the right strings but doesn't append `dataKey` to the link when I'm not one of the links I'm trying to build.

`dataKey` even prints out properly within the `<span>` `</span>`

However, when I navigate manually to one of the links, all the params are properly appended.

```
export const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home, beforeEnter: checkAuthentication },
  { path: '/dashboard',
    component: Dashboard,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardHome,
        name: 'Dashboard Home'
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        component: DashboardPhotos,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: DashboardPhotosHome,
            name: 'Dashboard Profile Home'
          },
          {
            path: ':dataKey',
            component: PhotoViewer,
            props: true
          }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: what is your dataObject?

Comment: @Sabrina it's a computed property from vuex store.

Comment: Can you add code corresponding to relevant routes as well and also provide sample of `dataObject `.

Comment: @Saurabh updated.

Comment: Possible to create a fiddle of this?